# Gradle plugin not executing command correctly on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I have the following line in my gradle plugin code

```
def cmd = "./gradlew -q ":app:dependencies --configuration compile"
def proc = cmd.execute()
def output = proc.text.trim()
```

When i execute gradle command on my local machine

```
./gradlew clean build
```

I can see correct value in output variable. But when i run the same command via jenkins job , variable output has no value in it.

i'm not able to figure out what's going on here.

My local machine is mac and remote jenkins box is linux

Comment: Not sure what your trying to accomplish.  seems like at best this would cause a loop.  Do you want to add a task to the build?  What is the actual goal?

Comment: @JBirdVegas Well i'm trying to fix a plugin written by some one. The objective is to get a list of all dependencies of a project during release build and capture it in a note. I'm thinking using project object to get compile time build dependency would have been better. May be i'll enhance the code in future. For now i found the issue was related to some command line argument. Since the code is only using Sysout stream from proc object and ignoring err stream, it was not showing the error cause. After setting the command line argument the problem is solved for now.

Comment: Is this code in the same build as the project `app`?  Under 'What context does the code shown run? In a plugin or in something else's `build.gradle`?

Comment: The code is inside a plugin that gets applied to the app build script. So at runtime a task from the plugin is executed to get app dependencies.

Comment: Got it... Your going through a lot of extra unnecessary steps.  Let me throw together some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the dependency graph without calling `gradlew` again.

Really all you want is a plugin with a task that runs after `dependencyReport` and reads the file created.  This should do it for you.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
}

apply plugin: DepReport

class DepReport implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.pluginManager.apply('project-report')
        def reportTask = project.tasks.create('myReport', DepTask) {
            group = 'reports'
            description = "Create our report"
        }
        reportTask.dependsOn 'dependencyReport'
        reportTask.outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    }
}

class DepTask extends DependencyInsightReportTask {
    @OutputFile
    def output = new File("$project.buildDir.absolutePath/reports/project", "dependencies.txt")

    DepTask() {
        configuration = project.configurations.getByName('compile')

    }

    @Override
    @TaskAction
    void report() {
        def dependencies = output.text.trim()
        println "Found dependencies to be $dependencies.chars.length chars long"
        // you could print them or manipulate the text as desired but the text is large
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./gradlew myReport
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:dependencyReport
:app:myReport
Found dependencies to be 1301 chars long

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.712 secs
```